# ios: Increase width of custom view in UIViewController while run on iphone6

Tags: ios, autolayout, autoresize

I am having one custom view which is base class of UIView and i have use that view in my view controller.

My custom view is having 4 buttons and my custom views height is 200 and width is 320.

When i run my project it works fine with iPhone 4 and 5 but dose not work with iPhone6. width of custom view remains same.

I have tried with Autoresizing and Auto layout but it dose not help.

Here in my UIView I have add the following Constraints..

[image: Here in my UIView I have add the following Constraints..]

Please let me know what i m missing or any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable autoresizing and use autolayout only. if you have problems with the constraints, please post your dirty layout.